# how do i act in user context c# sql application

Tags: c#, sql, session

In a c# application with SQLExpress, I'm trying to store user details after login. Let's say users are already put into the database by another form. In a dashboard, there is some data analysis with SQL queries and grids. Relevant metadata for those queries are the following user attributes.

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }
}
```

The Login button:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from userlogin where benutzername = @Username and passwort = @Password;", conn);                       
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", rjTextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", rjTextBox2.Text);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        Dashboard db = new Dashboard();
        db.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

In the Dashboard, I need to pass things like the id, username, and DOB to use the values in queries and query data for the currently logged-in user or alert if GETDATE() == currentuser.dob etc..

Do I even need those properties? How would you handle this?

Comment: NEVER store a password in plain text.  Passwords should be hashed.

Comment: I thought about adding a var currentuser = new User() and passing everything else with params but maybe there is some contemporary method

Comment: I need to figure out this problem before attending to store real user data and handle password secure

Comment: Contemporary?  Use EF and IdentityServer, which will handle user accounts securely.

Comment: Thanks thats some keywords to work with